# Does Unity have 'registration modules'?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, unity-container

After working with Ninject and SimpleInjector for years, I'm pretty used to separating my registrations into various modules which I can load based on configuration etc. Also, they extremely help to reduce the clutter of a huge wall of registration code.

```
public UserModule : NinjectModule {
    public override Load() {
        Kernel.Bind<IUserAuthenticationService>()...
    }
}
```

Does Unity support something like this? Googling and reading through the official docs brought nothing up.

Comment: *Googling and reading through the official docs brought nothing up* I tried searching google, not more than one minute; I found the duplicate question. Search keyword is "unity container modules" and first hit is the duplicate link :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel lol I googled for Unity in combination with "ninject" as I didn't know Autofac also had modules. Good to know!

Comment: A modules/installers/registries feature is usually very useless, because in most cases you can achieve the same by extracting the relevant code to a public static class and call that class from within your main application. Modules are especially useful in cases you want to load assemblies dynamically without having a compile-time dependency, which is only useful in plugin scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Unity Extension and provide registrations as part of this extension.

```
Container.RegisterExtension<MyModule>(...);
```